# Powershell script: Create file on TFS server using New-Item

Tags: powershell, tfs

Able to create file on local server with this command.

```
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
New-Item -Path $ScriptDir\NITI_20180402.223.txt -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."
```

But file is not created when build this script on TFS server.

```
New-Item -Path $ScriptDir\NITI_20180402.223.txt -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."
```

Comment: How are you defining your variables in the build script?  Your two examples don't match.

Comment: Modified question

Comment: What version is powershell on for your TFS server?  Try `New-Item ... -Verbose 4> Logfile.txt`

Comment: New-Item -Path $ScriptDir\abc.txt -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string." -Verbose 4

Getting error: potential parameter can not be found that accepts argument '4'

Comment: Have you tried specifying an absolute path manually instead of using your $ScriptPath variable? Or outputting the value of $ScriptPath to see if something weird is set there?

Comment: @niti parikh How did you run the script on TFS server? Does the agent service account have the write permission to access the target path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the script on my side, everything works as expected.

Whatever you can try this (Add `-Force`):

```
New-Item -Path $ScriptDir\NITI_20180402.223.txt -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string." -Force
```

If that still not work, please share your build definition settings (capture screenshot is better) and the logs for further troubleshooting.

[image]

Comment: @nitiparikh Have you resolved the issue? any update?